# Finding a probability when there is a biased die

Tags: probability, statistics, prime-numbers, even-and-odd-functions

Let W
be the number shown on a biased die. It is known that ℙ(=)=0.2 for 
w
even, and also that the probability the die shows a prime number is 0.5. What is ℙ(=1)?

[Note: You can assume the die has six sides.]

How do i approach this question as generally i would draw a pmf table however doing this gives me more than 1 which indicates that it is incorrect, any tips?

My working out -
P(w=2,4,6)=.2
P(w=2,3,5)=0.5
As 2 is common i multiplied give p(w=2)=0.10

Comment: Hard to tell if you don't show your work, but I guess you are taking the second condition to mean $\Pr(W=2)=\Pr(W=3)=\Pr(W=5)=.5$, whereas the problem actually means $\Pr(W\in\{2,3,5\})=.5$

Comment: "*I multiplied give p(w=2)=...*"  No.  $\Pr(A\cap B)$ is *not* equal to $\Pr(A)\times \Pr(B)$ in general.  This will *only* be true when they are independent events and this may not be assumed to be true for events in general... there are plenty of examples of dependent events in which case doing this will give the incorrect answer.

Comment: If you are making that mistake, then I expect you will make the related mistake of thinking that $\Pr(A\cup B)=\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)$ which is also incorrect.  That would have been valid when $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive events which is again not going to be true in general.  The correct statements that you should remember are instead $\Pr(A\cap B) = \Pr(A)\times \Pr(B\mid A)$ and that $\Pr(A\cup B) = \Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-\Pr(A\cap B)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $P(W=2) = P(W=4) = P(W=6) = 0.2$, and that $0.5 = P(W\in\{2,3,5\}) = P(W=2)+ P(W=3) + P(W=5)$. This implies that $P(W=3) + P(W=5) = 0.3$.

As we also know that
$\begin{align*}
1 &= P(W=1) + P(W=2) + P(W=3) + P(W=4) + P(W=5) + P(W=6)\\
 &= P(W=1) + 0.2 + 0.2 + 0.2 + (P(W=3) + P(W=5))\\
&= P(W=1) + 0.6 + 0.3
\end{align*}$
we can calculate the value of $P(W=1)$.